# Error while running rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

Getting error while running `rake routes`. Please suggest.

```
$ rake routes

rake aborted! 
LoadError: incompatible library version -
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in
`require'
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in
`rescue in <top (required)>'
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/latei/Desktop/rails/alpha-blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>' /home/latei/Desktop/rails/alpha-blog/Rakefile:4:in
`require_relative' /home/latei/Desktop/rails/alpha-blog/Rakefile:4:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in
`<top (required)>' LoadError: cannot load such file --
sqlite3/2.3/sqlite3_native
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in
`require'
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/latei/Desktop/rails/alpha-blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>' /home/latei/Desktop/rails/alpha-blog/Rakefile:4:in
`require_relative' /home/latei/Desktop/rails/alpha-blog/Rakefile:4:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/latei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in
`<top (required)>' (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: type bundle in your console

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you may be lacking the necessary development library required to use the sqlite gem.

In debian this can be installed using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install libsqlite-3`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think the problem is in your gem version, Try this one:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.10'
```

and then `$ bundle install`

Comment: if you satisfy with my ans then make it correct and vote up